# Subgit ignores definied /tags/ we don't want to synch

Tags: git, svn, tags, subgit

We are using SubGit to sync a remote SVN repository with our git repository and want to get the tags from the svn.
The problem is that we only want to sync non archived tags that are not in  the tags/archive folder. 
To exclude this directory, we tried to use the skip option of SubGit, which is not working. We can’t find a proper documentation on this feature either.

Our config: (in [svn])

```
skip = "^archive(\\/|$)"
skip = "^tags/archive(\\/|$)"
tags = tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

Both of the skip options are not working and the archive folder is synced.
Is there a way to get the skip option working or is there another way to exclude a tag directory from syncing.

We are using SubGit version 2.0.3

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`skip` option is not documented because in version 3.0 it was replaced with `excludePath` and `includePath` options and it's highly recommended to upgrade to version 3.0.

All these 3 options ignore only files and directories **within** trunk, branches/branch, tags/tag paths, e.g. in your example your patterns ignore `tags/*/archive` and `tags/*/tags/archive` but don't ignore `tags/archive` itself.

Since version 3.0 what you want is easy to achieve:

```
[svn]
tags = tags/*:refs/tags/*
excludeBranches = tags/archive
```

You can find documentation on the options in `subgit/config` file generated by SubGit of version >= 3.0.

To upgrade to the newer version of SubGit run

```
$ subgit install path/to/repository
```

with the newer version.

Comment: Dmitry, can you please add the SubGit upgrade instructions for existing repositories to SubGit docs? I was looking for it in SubGit docs, but could not find it, Google search brought me here.